# AOP not intercepting in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-aop

I've a method in Spring Batch Item Writer that I want to run @After on it, but for some reason the AOP Advice isn't running after the method returns.

The code goes as follows:

```
package com.mypackage.item;
// some imports

@Slf4j
@Component
@StepScope
public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends MyClass> items) throws Exception {
      for (MyClass myClass : items) {
        Status status = doWork(myClass);
        log.info(status);
      }
    }

    public Status doWork(MyClass myClass) {
        return doLotsOfWork(myClass);
    }
}
```

And the AOP advice:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class OperationsAop {

    @AfterReturning(
          pointcut="execution(* com.mypackage.item.MyItemWriter.doWork(..)) && args(myClass))",
  returning="retValue")
    public void invokeAfterDoWork(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retValue, MyClass myClass) {
    .... some stuff here
    }
}
```

doWork is getting invoked correctly and return status, but the advice isn't getting called. I think the pointcut expression is correct because I see an icon in IntelliJ beside both methods (advised and advice) where you can click on and navigate to the other one. However I'm not sure why it's not getting called.

Some setup info:

```
springBootVersion = "1.5.4.RELEASE"

compile (group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-jetty", version: "${springBootVersion}")
compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-aop", version: "${springBootVersion}"
```

The AOP class is definitely loading because I can see this in the debug logs:

```
Found AspectJ method public void com.mypackage.aop.OperationsAop.invokeAfterDoWork(org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint,java.lang.Object,com.mypackage.domain.MyClass)
```

Based on M.Deinum comment, I did some search and come along this suggestion from [Spring Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)

> The key thing to understand here is that the client code inside the main(..) of the Main class has a reference to the proxy. This means that method calls on that object reference will be calls on the proxy, and as such the proxy will be able to delegate to all of the interceptors (advice) that are relevant to that particular method call. However, once the call has finally reached the target object, the SimplePojo reference in this case, any method calls that it may make on itself, such as this.bar() or this.foo(), are going to be invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a chance to execute.
>
> Okay, so what is to be done about this? The best approach (the term best is used loosely here) is to refactor your code such that the self-invocation does not happen. For sure, this does entail some work on your part, but it is the best, least-invasive approach.

Comment: Spring AOP uses proxies, as a result only method calls into the object will get aspects applied, internal method calls don't pass through the proxy.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum is there a way to achieve what I want to do? Maybe by restructuring the code? You can also add your comment as an answer

Comment: Wyh do you want to use the aspect? The aspect is only applicable here, so hardly a cross cutting concern I would say. Why not simply implement it in the code itself instead of using an aspect.

Comment: the aspect isn't only here, the code in the question is heavily massaged

Comment: Move the `doWork` to an external class you can then intercept that method call as it will be an external method call.

Comment: @M.Deinum yup did that and now it works! Thanks. You can add your comments in an answer if you want